# named pipe in unix

Tags: unix, named-pipes

my program has two processes.one process writes to FIFO(named pipe) and must wait until another process read from FIFO and then it waits for that process to return the result(writing to FIFO to be read by this process).
my question is that how to know the data is read form FIFO by another process and then call read() system call for result?

Answer (score 0):

Most UNIXen have bidirectional pipes (man pipe)

Linux, IIRC hasn't got those, so you need to use `socket_pair`, which can conveniently use UNIX domain sockets giving roughly the same functionality.

In my experience porting code often required little else beyond replacing the call to `pipe` by a call to `socket_pair`